# drag and drop email attachment file from Outlook to a web application

Tags: drag-and-drop, outlook

We import data from Excel files into a Java web application.

The users want to drag and drop Excel files incoming as email attachment in Outlook (2003 and 2007) into the web app and browser (Chrome).

Outlook does not allow an Excel file attachment to be dropped into a browser window. What would be the easiest way to enable this?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295522/drag-and-drop-outlook-message-into-browser/49679156

Answer (score 3):

*disclaimer - I'm the creator of this product.*

You can use [Outlook2Web](http://outlook2web.com) to do this. It let's you drag files in emails or the emails themselves directly to web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't think of anything that directly answers your question however an alternative scenario could work. Namely if you're using an exchange server you could use the WebUI to do what you need. If you're using Google apps or any other webmail services then use their WebUI. If you're using simple POP and SMTP then I would setup Squirrel Mail on a LAMP install, it creates a WebUI for any POP and SMTP accessible email service.

Sorry I couldn't answer your question directly but I hope these alternatives are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems (based on the answer to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/441747/dragging-attachments-from-outlook-into-applications) that Outlook doesn't add the needed "accepted format" for doing this (CF_HDROP).

The alternative they suggest might not be too good for you either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Outlook File Drag is what you are looking for.
https://github.com/tonyfederer/OutlookFileDrag

It works with attachments but not with built-in mail pictures.
Enjoy